# sails lifecycle - custom service and config.log

Tags: sails.js

I defined a l.js under /api/services

```
exports.i = sails.log.info;
exports.v = sails.log.verbose;
exports.err = sails.log.error;
exports.w = sails.log.warn;
exports.d = sails.log.debug;
```

It works fine but when I want to define custom logger in /config/log.js

```
let customLogger = new (winston.Logger)({
    transports: [
        new (winston.transports.Console, winston.transports.File)({
            name: 'file.info',
            level: 'info',
            filename: logPath + '/server-info.log',
            json: true
        }),
        new (winston.transports.Console, winston.transports.File)({
            name: 'file.warning',
            level: 'warning',
            filename: logPath + '/server-warning.log',
            json: true
        }),
        new (winston.transports.File)({
            name: 'file.error',
            level: 'error',
            filename: logPath + '/server-error.log',
            json: true
        })
    ]
});

module.exports.log = {
    level: 'info',
    custom: customLogger,
};
```

When I use `sails.log.error("123"); l.err("456")` in controller, only "123" showed in server-error.log file. "456" only print to console.

When I check sails doc about lifecycle, it seems /config/log.js loaded before /api/services. How should I modify my code?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although `config/log.js` is loaded before `api/services/l.js`, (my feeling is) assignment of custom logger defined in log.js to `sails.log.<level>` happens after the service is loaded.

Hence the behavior.

Re-assigning on `lifted` event fixes this. Use this code in `l.js`:

```
exports.err = sails.log.error;

sails.on('lifted', function() {
  console.log('lifted event');
  // Re-assign here
  exports.err = sails.log.error;
});
```

Do similarly for other methods of the service.

Comment: Really helpful. Thanks a lot!